# noSuchMethod Error coming

Tags: java, android, twilio

I am using four library

named as 1) twilio-sdk 3.10 
         2) twilioclient-android 
         3) android jar
         4) libtwilio-native.so

When i am using the `TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient("id","toknid")`

then i am getting error of

```
       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:   
      org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager. 
      03-21 13:19:11.223: E/AndroidRuntime(296): at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.
     (TwilioRestClient.java:137) 03-21 13:19:11.223: E/AndroidRuntime(296): 
  at   com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.(TwilioRestClient.java:108)
```

i had done a lot of R&D on this part ,there must be HTTP request Problem,Can any one tell me how to solve this problem

Please see the above Exception.

Comment: Please check with jd that the method called from TwilioRestClient.java line 137 is there or not. It may be due to the version mismatch

Comment: The exception message has been mangled.  You've chopped off the name of the actual missing method / constructor.

Comment: how could i able to solve it,could i share the code ?

Comment: sendNotification() ;   /* Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client */
  TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(sub_sid, sub_auth_token);
  //twilio-java-sdk-3.3.10-jar-with-dependencies.jar

  // Get the account and call factory class
  Account acct = client.getAccount();
  SmsFactory smsFactory = acct.getSmsFactory();

Comment: which is the 4th library? ;)

Comment: libtwilio-native.so this is the fourth one

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have some library (.jar) mismatch. That method indicates that a class is being found, but a referenced method is *not*.I suspect one library has been compiled against a particular version of the other, and that method is not present in the version you're supplying.

Comment: means i could use the higer version of twilio-java sdk ,new one is the twilio-java sdk 3.13.jar